# Does Knex w/ Sqlite need destroy to run multiple queries?

Tags: knex.js, node-sqlite3

I have a script that I am trying to generate my database schema with using Knex and Sqlite3. It looks like the following:

schema.js

```
const log = require('electron-log');
const app = require('electron').remote.app;
let knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: app.getPath('userData') + '/warframeData.db',
    },
});

async function create() {
    log.debug('Creating schema.');
    await createSchemaVersion()
        .then(createRelicTable)        
        .catch((err) => log.debug(err));
}

function createSchemaVersion() {
    log.debug('calling Create Schema Version');
    return knex.schema
        .createTableIfNotExists('schemaVersion', function (table) {
            table.string('name').unique().notNullable();
            table.integer('major').notNullable();
            table.integer('minor').notNullable();
            table.integer('patch').notNullable();
        })
        .then(() => {
            log.debug('Table schemaVersion created');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            log.error('Error creating table schemaVersion', err);
        })
}

function createRelicTable() {
    log.debug('calling Create Relics');
    return knex.schema
        .createTableIfNotExists('relics', function (table) {
            table.string('name').unique().notNullable().primary();
            table.integer('tradable').notNullable();
            table.string('url').notNullable();
            table.string('image').notNullable();
            table.integer('vaulted').notNullable();
        })
        .then(() => {
            log.debug('Table relics created');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            log.error('Error creating table relics', err);
        });
```

When I run this, the database gets created, the schemaVersion table gets created, but then it hangs. The log only yields this:

```
[2020-06-09 10:56:17.073] [debug] Creating schema.
[2020-06-09 10:56:17.074] [debug] calling Create Schema Version
```

Notice that neither the `then` nor `catch` for `createSchemaVersion` ever come through.

If I add a `.finally(() => knex.destroy())` to each of the knex actions - then everything works and I get the full log as I would expect, however the relic create obviously explodes because the knex object has been destroyed. So, if I remake the knex object in each function - then everything works fine.

But that just seems wrong. It seems like I should be able to re-use the knex object.

What is going on here? Do you really have to destroy/re-create the knex object every time?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this later, this was because I was calling this script from the electron renderer process instead of main. There were no errors or messages that I could find - but at another developer's suggestion, I tried calling the same script from Main.js and it worked just fine.

This is probably a newbie Electron mistake - but that's what I am so might as well own it.